# path with max sum in tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Given a Binary tree with -ve and +ve value's. print all path's froom root to any node with max sum.do it in O(n). only one traversal of tree.

Efforts :)
1) http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-sum-path-in-a-binary-tree/                     is entirely    different problem .

2) O(n) + O(n) is not accepted .

my approach .

1)

i) find max sum possible .
ii) traverse preorder keeping current path and sum . if(curr_sum == max_sum) print path.

2)
i) find max sum possible .
ii) traverse preorder keeping current path and sum . 
    if(curr_sum == max_sum) print path. also save address of this node in a node array Arr.
    next time when curr_sum==max_sum just check in Arr[]
 if path is already printed

problem :
 this will print some paths multiple time's . more over interviewer wanted one traversal .  this takes 2. one to find max sum . other to print paths.

Comment: O(n) + O(n) = O(n) , just so you know. If you'd like I can easily prove it.

Comment: sir i know that well :) . so i clarified it with interviewer. he was very clear traverse tree only once .

Comment: Seems like a trick question. Iiuc, it will be an O(n log n) task just to print the paths.

Answer (score 2):

Do a Depth-First-Search on the tree, computing sums for all sub-paths and store them in a sorted array of lists containing sub-paths of equal length. It's easy to see that this can be done in O(n), traversing the graph exactly once.

The result is an array `a` where `a[i]` contains a list of paths of length `i`. Keep record of the largest index `j` and eventually print all paths in the list `a[j]`.

Comment: @user1992592: can you be a bit more clear? What part is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Let's say we are traversing tree preorder . at any node we can't be sure that it's max path till here since child node's can be +ve or negative . so we need one traversal to get max_sum.

Comment: also i don't get how you are saving all paths ?.
 how is this better then my (2) solution ?